# Find all differences in sorted array

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, binary-search

I have a sorted (ascending) array of real values, call it a (duplicates possible). I wish to find, given a range of values [x, y], all indices of values (i) for which an index j exists such that:
    j>i and 
    x <= a[j]-a[i] <= y
Or simply put, find values in which exists a “forward difference” within a given range.

The output is a Boolean array of length a.Length. 
Since the array is sorted all forward differences, x and y are positive.

The best I’ve managed to do is start from each index looking at the subarray in front of it and perform a binary search for x+a[i] and check if a[j]<=y+a[i]. I think this is O(n log n). 
Is there a better approach? Or something I can do to speed things up.

I should note that eventually I want to perform the search for many such ranges [x,y] over the same array a, but the number of ranges is very much smaller than the length of the array (4-6 orders of magnitude smaller) - therefore I’m far more concerned with the complexity of the search.

Example:

```
a= 0, 1, 46, 100, 185, 216, 285
```

with range x,y=[99,101] should return:

```
[true, true, false, false, true, false, false]
```

For only values 0,1 and 185 have a forward difference within the range.

Code from memory, might have some bugs:

```
int bin_search_closesmaller(int arr[], int key, int low, int high)
{
    if (low > high) return high;
    int mid = (high - low)/2;
    if (arr[mid] > key) return bin_search_closesmaller(arr, key, low, mid - 1);
    if (arr[mid] < key) return bin_search_closesmaller(arr, key, mid + 1, high);
    return mid;
}

bool[] findDiffs(int[] a, int x, int y)
{
    bool[] result = new bool[a.Length];
    for(int i=0; i<a.Length-1;i++)
    {
        int idx=bin_search_closesmaller(a, y+a[i], i+1, a.Length-1);
        if (idx==-1) continue;
        if (a[idx]-a[i] >= x) result[i]=true;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you add a single example array and range?

Comment: `The best I’ve managed to do` - Could you show your attempt? This is an interesting question and I would hate to see it closed due to lack of code in the question.

Comment: @NightOwl888 I added my attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the input array is sorted, there is a linear solution to the problem. The key is to use two indexes to traverse of the array `a`.

```
bool[] findDiffs(int[] a, int x, int y)
{
  bool[] result = new boolean[a.Length];
  int j = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; ++i) {
    while (j < a.Length && a[j] - a[i] < x) {
      ++j;
    }
    if (j < a.Length) {
      result[i] = a[j] - a[i] <= y;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

With `a = [0,100,1000,1100]` and `(x,y) = (99,100)`:

```
i = 0, j = 0 => a[j] - a[i] = 0 < x=99     => ++j
i = 0, j = 1 => a[j] - a[i] = 100 <= y=100 => result[i] = true; ++i
i = 1, j = 1 => a[j] - a[i] = 0 < x=99     => ++j
i = 1, j = 2 => a[j] - a[i] = 900 > y=100  => result[i] = false; ++i
i = 2, j = 2 => a[j] - a[i] = 0 <= x=99    => ++j
i = 2, j = 3 => a[j] - a[i] = 100 <= y=100 => result[i] = true; ++i
i = 3, j = 3 => a[j] - a[i] = 0 <= x=99    => exit loop
```

Answer (score 3):

Make two indexes `left` and `right` and walk through array. `Right` index moves until it goes out of range for current `left` one, then check whether previous element is in range. Indexes move only forward, so algorithm is linear

```
 right=2
 for left = 0 to n-1:
    while A[right] < A[left] + MaxRangeValue
       right++
    Result[left] =  (A[right - 1] <= A[left] + MinRangeValue)
```

Another point of view on this algorithm:
-while difference is too low, increment right
-while difference is too high, increment left